# Add condition in step function using aws python cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

I am creating a step function and there is a condition like this

if my step output is "is_query" : True  then I have to move a different step and if false then I have to go to diffrent step I am following this example   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions/README.html

I got idea from this like this :

for example If I do something like this :

```
sfn_step_1.next(sfn_step_2).next(sfn.Choice(self, "Job Complete?").when(sfn.Condition.string_equals("$.is_query", "True"), sfn_special_step ).when(sfn.Condition.string_equals("$.is_query", "False"), Do Nothing ).next(sfn_step_3)
```

So I have 2 questions how I can make this Do Nothing and move to step 3 as at the end I want both to go to step 3 . just a extra step in  is_query to True case. And 2nd question how I can add "is_query", "True" to payload for now my step 2 payload look like this :

```
sfn_step_2 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "check-status",
                                lambda_function=check_status_lambda,
                                output_path="$.Payload",
                                integration_pattern=stepfunctions.IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
                                payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                    "payload.$": "$",
                                    "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
                                    "taskToken": stepfunctions.JsonPath.task_token
                                })
                                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the second condition just add

> .afterwards()).next(your next step)

this will solve both problems.

on your code is like this:

```
sfn_step_1.next(sfn_step_2).next(sfn.Choice(self, "Job Complete?").when(sfn.Condition.string_equals("$.is_query", "True"), sfn_special_step ).afterwards()).next(sfn_step_3)
```

Comment: didn't get can you please change whole string please ?

Comment: `sfn_step_1.next(sfn_step_2).next(sfn.Choice(self, "Job Complete?").when(sfn.Condition.string_equals("$.is_query", "True"), sfn_special_step ).afterwards()).next(sfn_step_3)`

Comment: Thanks got it. and 2nd thing which I asked can you please guide about that aswell ? like how I can  pass this condition etc ?  as I was running this step function without any condition

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, please explain more. :)

Comment: getting this error :. Failed to transition out of the state. The state does not point to a next state. when I am passing False .